# How can I bind model to NSTableView?

Tags: swift

I'm calling the delegate method `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` to load data. Every time when my model changes I need to call `NSTableView.reload()` to refresh the tableView. How can I bind model to `NSTableView` ?

```
extension MyViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let identifier = tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue as String?

        if identifier == "AppName" {
            let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "AppName"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
            cell.imageView?.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: AppData.appList[row]["icon"] as! String))
            cell.textField?.stringValue = AppData.appList[row]["name"] as! String

            return cell
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `NSArrayController`
- Bind `Content` of the table view to `arrangedObjects` of the array controller (leave `Model Key Path` empty).
- Bind `Value` of each text field to `Table Cell View` > `ObjectValue` > property or `key`.

Alternatively

- Implement `numberOfRows` and `objectValueForColumn:row` and connect `data source`
- Bind `Value` of each text field to `Table Cell View` > `ObjectValue` > property or `key`.
- Insert and delete data with `insertRows` and `removeRows` methods.

It's highly recommended to use a custom class as model rather than a dictionary.